# Is a text node considered a child of it's element?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have this problem.

```
<b>Problem #14</b>: Remove all "div" with no child elements.
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel14" CssClass="Problem" runat="server">
        <div>
            <span>I have a child</span>
        </div>
        <div>I have no children</div>
        <div>
            <i>I have another child</i>
            <b>I am the second child</b>
        </div>
        <div></div>
    </asp:Panel>
```

This is my jQuery:

```
 $("#Panel14 div:empty").remove();
```

This is the result:

[Screenshot of Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8lDL.png)

```
<div id="Panel14" class="Problem">  
        <div>
            <span>I have a child</span>
        </div>
        <div>I have no children</div>
        <div>
            <i>I have another child</i>
            <b>I am the second child</b>
        </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, it only removes the `<div></div>`. It leaves behind `<div>I have no children</div>` and I can't figure out why, so I started wondering whether an element with text was considered an element with a child (that being the text node). I looked for documentation one way or the other and the closest I've found is this:

[W3Schools.com - The HTML DOM Document Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp)

> In the HTML DOM (Document Object Model), everything is a node:
>   The document itself is a document node.
>   All HTML elements are element nodes.
>   All HTML attributes are attribute nodes.
>   Text inside HTML elements are text nodes.
>   Comments are comment nodes.

Is my jQuery wrong or is it perhaps a trick question, and that DIV actually does have a child (the text)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. this will check to make sure the div does not have any children elements. using not(:has(*)) wildcard checking for any elements

```
$("#Panel14 div:not(:has(*))").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Raw text nodes are mostly ignored by jQuery and many are just whitespace. They *are* child nodes in the DOM though.

`:empty` basically checks if the innerHTML of the element is blank, so will fail if there is text. This kind of makes sense as it is not "empty".

If you just want to access nodes with no standard "jQuery" children use a wildcard descendant selector with `:has` and `:not`:

```
$('.Problem div:not(:has(*))')
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/chntm3j6/

**Note:** You need to get jQuery `contents()` if you want to examine *all* child nodes.

Answer (score -1):

This is just a wild attempt,not tested ,do try and let me know.

```
if( $("#Panel14 div").children().size()>0)
{
        $(this).remove();
}
else
{
     if($(this).text()=="")
         $(this).remove();
}
```